# How to fix the column alignment in my code?

Tags: java

This is just for the sake of formality/neatness. Backlash t (\t), which is all I know, doesn't seem to work very well. Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RegisterStudent {

public static void register() {
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Student Class Card Evaluation System");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    System.out.println("Personal Data");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\tEnter student no.: ");
    long studNo = input.nextLong();
    System.out.print("\tEnter first name: ");
    String fName = input.next();
    System.out.print("\tEnter last name: ");
    String lName = input.next();
    System.out.print("\tEnter course: ");
    String course = input.next();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Subject: Computer Programming 2");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("\tPrelim Grade: ");
    double pg = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\tMidterm Grade: ");
    double mg = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\tPrefinal Grade: ");
    double pfg = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("\tFinal Grade: ");
    double fg = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

    double gwa = (pg + mg + pfg + fg)/4;    

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Student Evaluated successfully...");
    System.out.println("Viewing Report...");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("ID No.\t\t" + "LASTNAME\t\t" + "FIRSTNAME\t\t" + "COURSE\t\t"
        + "PG\t\t" + "MG\t\t" + "PFG\t\t" + "FG\t\t" + "GWA");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");

    System.out.println(studNo + "\t\t" + lName + "\t\t" + fName + "\t\t" + course + "\t\t"
        + pg + "\t\t" + mg + "\t\t" + pfg + "\t\t" + fg + "\t\t" + gwa);
```

The output should look something like this:
[image: output]

Everything that the user will input should be properly aligned. Please help me fix my program, thanks guys!

---

My current output is this:
[image: IMG]

You see it's not properly aligned

Comment: So what's the current output? and what's wrong with it?

Comment: `System.out.print("\tEnter student no.: ");` => `System.out.print("\tEnter student no.:\t");` would be closer to the expected output.

Comment: Given a fixed tab length, your approach will work with the top lines with no problem. However, it won't (easily) work with the last line, because the number of needed successive tabs varies with the length of `studNo`, `lName` and `fName`. Take a look at the [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method or, for example, Guava's [String padding](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Strings.html#padEnd%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20char%29).

Answer (score 6):

Since this is homework, here are a couple of hints:

- The `printf` method on a `PrintWriter` or `PrintStream` classes can do alignment.  So can `String.format` and the `Formatter` class.
- Don't use TAB characters (i.e. `'\t'`) for alignment in simple text output if you want the alignment to be portable.  Different OSes have different ideas on the "width" of a TAB.

Answer (score 0):

The number of tabs you need on each line of input will be determined by the length of the prompt text which appears first on the line i.e. the shorter the prompt, the more tabs required. Simple trial and error should sort out your output to give you the required result.